# I had Created an app in pyqt it have icons .I'm using pyinstaller to make it exe how can i add icon in Exe

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
window.show() # IMPORTANT!!!!! Windows are hidden by default.

# Start the event loop.
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use command --icon while creating exe

```
<<cmd your path >>$pyinstaller --noconsole --icon "c:\icon.ico" pythoncode.py
```